Is there a way to cleanup navigation transition code in jetpack compose
I have the following code in my NavHost. The enterTransition, exitTransition, popEnterTransition and popExitTransition code is repeated for all the routes that I add to my NavHost. How do I clean it.
NavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = CreateProjectRoute,
) {
    composable<ProjectsListRoute>(
        enterTransition = {
            slideIntoContainer(
                AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Left,
                tween(500)
            )
        },
        exitTransition = {
            slideOutOfContainer(
                AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Left,
                tween(500)
            )
        },
        popExitTransition = {
            slideOutOfContainer(
                AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Right,
                tween(500)
            )
        },
        popEnterTransition = {
            slideIntoContainer(
                AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Right,
                tween(500)
            )
        }
    ) {
        ProjectsListScreen(
            onCreateButtonClicked = {
                navController.navigate(CreateProjectRoute)
            }
        )
    }
    composable<CreateProjectRoute>(
        enterTransition = {
            slideIntoContainer(
                AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Left,
                tween(500)
            )
        },
        exitTransition = {
            slideOutOfContainer(
                AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Left,
                tween(500)
            )
        },
        popExitTransition = {
            slideOutOfContainer(
                AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Right,
                tween(500)
            )
        },
        popEnterTransition = {
            slideIntoContainer(
                AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Right,
                tween(500)
            )
        }
    ) {
        CreateProjectScreen(
            viewModel = projectViewModel,
            navController = navController
        )
    }
}

I have tried creating functions like these:
fun defaultEnterTransition() = slideIntoContainer(
    AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Left,
    tween(500)
)

and using them in nav routes like this:
composable<ProjectsListRoute>(
        enterTransition = { defaultEnterTransition() }
    ) { }

but I get the following error: Unresolved reference: slideIntoContainer

you can create your own extension function on NavGraphBuilder something like below and assign the default animation in the builder as you want.
public inline fun <reified T : Any> NavGraphBuilder.slideComposable(
    typeMap: Map<KType, NavType<*>> = emptyMap(),
    noinline content: @Composable AnimatedContentScope.(NavBackStackEntry) -> Unit
) {
    destination(
        ComposeNavigatorDestinationBuilder(
            provider[ComposeNavigator::class],
            T::class,
            typeMap,
            content
        )
            .apply {
                this.enterTransition = {
                    slideIntoContainer(
                        AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Left,
                        tween(500)
                    )
                }
                this.exitTransition = {
                    slideOutOfContainer(
                        AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Left,
                        tween(500)
                    )
                }
                this.popEnterTransition = {
                        slideIntoContainer(
                            AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Right,
                            tween(500)
                        )
                    }
                this.popExitTransition = {
                    slideOutOfContainer(
                        AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Right,
                        tween(500)
                    )
                }
                this.sizeTransform = sizeTransform
            }
    )
}


NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = LoginRoute,
        modifier = modifier,
    ) {

        slideComposable<LoginRoute> {
            LoginScreen(
                navigateToDashboard = { navController.navigate(it) }
            )
        }

        slideComposable<DashboardRoute> { backStackEntry ->
            val route = backStackEntry.toRoute<DashboardRoute>()
            DashboardScreen(route)
        }
    }

Now you can using slideComposable instead of composable in your nav graph.
Note: Some other params like deeplinks, etc are missing you can add it as when needed.
